# .htaccess - removing parameters has added index.php despite site not using them

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am going around in circles.

Added utm_campaign= to a URL to track clicks via Google Analytics, but don't want the browser showing that URL afterwards, as it's an internal link.

Found htaccess code to remove the string, but it's now adding index.php where the entire site is set up to not use them, so can't work out how to remove.

e.g. going from `website.com/page?utm_campaign=CAMPAIGN`
to `website.com/index.php/page`
when I would like `website.com/page`.

The code I have for this task currently is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "utm_campaign=" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Code is:

Comment: you are hitting link `website.com/page?utm_campaign=CAMPAIGN` and want it to redirect to `website.com/index.php/page` in browser? Please confirm once.

Comment: No, I want ```website.com/page?utm_campaign=CAMPAIGN``` to redirect to ```website.com/page``` 

It is currently redirecting to ```website.com/index.php/page```.

Comment: What _else_ do you have in your .htaccess?

Comment: But I would rather do this with JavaScript on the client side (keyword: HTML5 History API), than make a redirect from the server side ...

Comment: _"to track clicks via Google Analytics"_ - track them where? At the origin (where the link gets clicked), or at the target (on your page, when the user _arrives_ at that URL)? If it is the latter, then it would be counterproductive if you removed this parameter from the URL, before any client-side tracking code has even had any chance to "see" it.

Comment: Clicks at the origin - we're already obviously tracking people who view the page, but it's specifically people clicking from that one link - which GA help pages say this can do.

I just then don't want that to be the URL people see and share afterwards. 

The htaccess file is huge - already has removing index.php from urls, which is why I find it odd this is adding it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
# BEGIN Google Analytics utm query string remove
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
# END Google Analytics utm query string remove
```

I tried in local xampp environment now and it works for me.

*But, however as @CBroe said its preferred to go with JavaScript on the client side.*

Comment: That's doing exactly as before, sending to a URL including index.php, unfortunately.

Comment: To get some more insights kindly let me know whats your environment. is it local deployment or any web hosting cpanel/plesk or any other ?

Comment: also let me know whether is this the full content of your htaccess ? or any other rules are there following this

Comment: @EmmaSwann Try this once and let me know 
 # BEGIN Google Analytics utm query string remove
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
# END Google Analytics utm query string remove